# Let's update our on-topic help page

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-scope

As some of you have noticed, our initial on-topic help page didn't really do much to [define the site scope](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/213/70) or [explain what we mean by open data](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7/70).

It was time to change this.

Please have a look at the [current version of the on-topic page](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). If you have any suggestions, please add them as an answer below, and we'll see that they are added to the on-topic page.

Answer (score 3):

Should we explicitly say that the Semantic Web (SPARQL, ontologies, etc) is [on](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/247/are-all-semantic-web-technology-questions-on-topic)-[topic](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233/are-rdf-vocabularies-ontologies-on-topic) here?

Even though the Semantic Web *might* be able for closed data, 99% of its usage is for open data.

The Semantic Web has the potential to generate a lot of great questions that are sure to entertain the open data people here, so why not make it clearer that it is on-topic :-)

Comment: I added the ```linked data, vocabularies and ontologies``` bullet point — does that cover it?

Comment: @PatrickHoefler: How about "vocabularies, ontologies, linked data and associated technologies"?

Comment: I changed it to ```linked data, ontologies and related semantic technologies```, added a tag synonym ([vocabulary](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vocabulary) --> [ontology](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ontology)), and linkified the tags that are already in use.

Comment: Oh, and I almost forgot: Thanks for your input! :)

Answer (score 0):

well done...here are my thoughts: link to the twitter url, as well as any others that exist. also somehow work an #opendata hashtag in there to let people know of its existence, as well as encourage them to use it.

maybe post friendly links, similar to reddit; offhand, data science so and gis so are probably the most aligned, though heavier users would know better.

i would like to see something in regards to a collection of sets that come through here; my first thought is just to host them on github and keep a repo running, but i'm not familiar with so's internals, so i'm blind when it comes to knowing what we can and can't do. or should/shouldn't do.

having a repo of all the sets would not only alert more people of our existence, but also send some traffic i'm sure.

that's all atm...i know i have more, but i'm spacing out.

i do think we should do something for open data day....

Comment: Wow, these are quite a few ideas :) ● As per [this discussion](http://meta.opendata.stackexchange.com/q/191/70), linking to our Twitter account currently doesn't make too much sense. I like the #OpenData hashtag, but I'm not sure how it would fit on our on-topic help page. ● Thanks for the idea about linking to GIS SE and DataScience SE, I've added a paragraph. ● Collecting the open datasets that are mentioned here on Open Data is definitely something we should think about. However, I believe this would be outside the scope of Stack Exchange.

Comment: i agree with that conversation, but it still exists and i see it tweet in my stream quite often. perhaps not promoting it is best here, but if its alive and being used, i see no reason why not to link to it. just my two cents. oh, there's also open source se in area 51 as of today

Comment: Thanks, I'm already keeping an eye on [Open Science SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65426/open-science?referrer=O-IOPlLN79ulvQRFh5DO2w2) and [Open Source SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/82234/open-source?referrer=txp09l1fzA115ew3W5QdwQ2). Currently they are both in the commitment phase.